# Why does Material slider takes extra padding at the start and the end?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

[image]

As you can see I have given the match_parent to the slider like below.

```
 <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:value="2"/>
```

I haven't given any extra padding or margin. Why isn't that fixed to the parent?

Comment: It has some space reserved to display a thumb at the start or end position.

Comment: @sdex Would you please share what is the exact size reserved to display a thumb?

Comment: Just open the Slider (BaseSlider) source code. There is some math.